# Babel does not convert ES6 to JavaScript that is understandable by browsers

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6, babeljs, gulp-babel

I use Gulp as task manager and Babel for convert my ES6 program to a version that is understandable for browsers, not for Node!

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('default', () =>
    gulp.src('src/app.js')
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['es2015']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
);
```

and in `src/app.js` I have:

```
import { square, diag } from 'lib';
//Some code here....
```

But, when I run the gulp, it make a file in `dist` but it converts `import` which is in `app.js` file to `require` keyword that is not understandable for browsers... I thought bable will merge `imported` files in `src/app.js` to one file in `dist`

How can I convert my library code to be supported by browsers using Babel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicly Babeljs converts your ES6 to ES5, Imagine you have an ES6 code:

```
const secret = ({ msg = 'es 6 hey!'} = {}) => () => msg;
```

The above code is in ES6, and Babeljs will help you to convert it to ES5:

```
'use strict';

var secret = function secret() {
  var _ref = arguments.length <= 0 || arguments[0] === undefined ? {} : arguments[0];

  var _ref$msg = _ref.msg;
  var msg = _ref$msg === undefined ? 'es 6 hey!' : _ref$msg;
  return function () {
    return msg;
  };
};
```

And `require` is not a *[current]* JavaScript standard, you need a 3rd-party library that also have a function named `require`, libraries like [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/), [browserify](http://browserify.org/), etc.

Even, if you have an ES6 program that includes any `export` or `import` keywords when you are working with [Babili](https://github.com/babel/babili) (online ES6 to ES5 converter) that will notify you that those converted keywords are not supported by browsers:

> require is not supported in the browser, you need a commonjs
>   environment such as node.js/io.js, browserify/webpack etc

[Online demo](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=import%20Class1%20from%20'file1'%3B%20%20%0D%0Aimport%20%7BClass2%2C%20class658%7D%20from%20'file2'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20obj%20%3D%20newClass1()%3B%0D%0Alet%20obj2%20%3D%20new%20Class2()%3B%0D%0A)

Comment: T.J. Crowder answer was good, but I needed more description. thanks for the answer

Comment: @theLisash No problem, glad that helped you

Comment: ES6 is not called harmony or ESNext (anymore). ESNext refers to future unreleased versions of ECMAScript, i.e. ES2017+.

Comment: @FelixKling Thank Felix, I just edited that and I also read Mozilla. I found it was called Harmoney and ES next before... Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Babel's job is to *transpile*. Combining and minifying scripts is a separate task.

You need to add [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/), [RequireJS](http://www.requirejs.org/), or similar, and then tell Babel that's what you're using so it emits code to use those. Some further information on [the setup page](http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/).

Comment: Thanks, May I ask, what is babel then? I thought it is converting my ES6 to browser supportable version!

Comment: @theLisash: Babel's job is to transpile the language. The job of these other tools is to provide a module system. Some of them also provide support for combining scripts based on the module dependencies. It's about using specific tools for specific jobs.

Comment: @theLisash You are lucky T.J Crowder answered your first question :) 
Babel is a essentially an ECMAScript 6 to ECMAScript 5 compiler